# Keep position of <li> hover state consistent

Tags: html, css

I have a grid list with hover states. I need to have it so it just adds the border. Currently, if you hover over each one the `li`/option shifts a little bit and causes the other items to shift. See the markup below:

HTML:

```
<div id="question13" class="question-options">
<h3 class="semi-bold">Header</h3>
<fieldset class="radio">
<ul>
<li class="border-blue">
<label><input type="radio" name="answers" class="semi-bold" value="8888">Option 1</label><span class="hide-text"></span>
</li>
<li class="border-blue">
<label><input type="radio" name="answers" class="semi-bold" value="8888">Option 2</label><span class="hide-text"></span>
</li>
<li class="border-blue">
<label><input type="radio" name="answers" class="semi-bold" value="8888">Option 3</label><span class="hide-text"></span>
</li>
<li class="border-blue">
<label><input type="radio" name="answers" class="semi-bold" value="8888">Option 4</label><span class="hide-text"></span>
</li>
</ul>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.question-options {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 20px;
  ul {
      display: grid;
      display: -ms-grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2,auto);
      li {
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
        margin: 0.5rem;
        position: relative;
      }
  }
}

.border-blue {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  &:hover {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
  }
}
```

Live fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c736cg6h/1/

Currently if you hover over each item, you see the item "shift around" and it affects the other items - I need to figure out how to keep it so that it just adds the border and does not affect the positioning of each item. I tried adding the same padding to the hover state and removing it but both seem to make it worse.

Is this caused by grid display? How can I just add a border on hover state without the positioning being affected?

Comment: Also use the border on regular state, same width, other color. Check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/c736cg6h/2/)

Comment: @JariRengeling You should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `border: 2px solid transparent;`

```css
.question-options {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 20px;
}
ul {
    display: grid;
    display: -ms-grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
}
li {
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    position: relative;
}

.border-blue {
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}
.border-blue:hover {
     padding: 10px;
     border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="question13" class="question-options">
    <h3 class="semi-bold">Header</h3>
    <fieldset class="radio">
        <ul>
            <li class="border-blue">
                <label><input type="radio" name="answers" class="semi-bold" value="8888">Option 1</label><span class="hide-text"></span>
            </li>
            <li class="border-blue">
                <label><input type="radio" name="answers" class="semi-bold" value="8888">Option 2</label><span class="hide-text"></span>
            </li>
            <li class="border-blue">
                <label><input type="radio" name="answers" class="semi-bold" value="8888">Option 3</label><span class="hide-text"></span>
            </li>
            <li class="border-blue">
                <label><input type="radio" name="answers" class="semi-bold" value="8888">Option 4</label><span class="hide-text"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid this by adding the same border, but transparent, to the regular (non-hover) state

```
.border-blue {
  [...]
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  [...]
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kgryvuco/1/

Answer (score 2):

Set a transparent `border` as initial state. Then colorize the `border` when you `:hover` it.

```
li {
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid transparent;

    &:hover {
       padding: 10px;
       border-color: blue;
    }
}
```

```css
.question-options {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 20px;
}

ul {
      display: grid;
      display: -ms-grid;
     grid-template-columns: repeat(2,auto);
  }
  
ul li {
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
        margin: 0.5rem;
        position: relative;
        border: 2px solid transparent;
}

.border-blue {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.border-blue:hover {
    padding: 10px;
    border-color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<div id="question13" class="question-options">
<h3 class="semi-bold">Header</h3>
<fieldset class="radio">
<ul>
<li class="border-blue">
<label><input type="radio" name="answers" class="semi-bold" value="8888">Option 1</label><span class="hide-text"></span>
</li>
<li class="border-blue">
<label><input type="radio" name="answers" class="semi-bold" value="8888">Option 2</label><span class="hide-text"></span>
</li>
<li class="border-blue">
<label><input type="radio" name="answers" class="semi-bold" value="8888">Option 3</label><span class="hide-text"></span>
</li>
<li class="border-blue">
<label><input type="radio" name="answers" class="semi-bold" value="8888">Option 4</label><span class="hide-text"></span>
</li>
</ul>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change in the hover padding to `8px`, the border adds `2px` so you will get `10px` total instead of `12px`

Answer (score 0):

If you decrease your `margin` size by the same amount you're increasing the total `div`, you should be good. You're setting margin to `8px`, so set it to `6px` instead on the hover. You also don't need to set the `padding` on the `hover`.

Since there are downvotes on some of these answers that are fully valid answers I thought I would explain a little more.

A CSS purest might shy away from achieving this using `border: 2px solid transparent;`. I don't think we need to worry about IE6 not being able to deal with transparent borders, but it's usually not recommended to use a "hack" to achieve what you want when you can do it another way, even if it is only IE6 and below that doesn't handle this well. Again, using it depends on a lot of other things.

The main issue is the fact that the `border` adds to the total size of the element. So, you have to accommodate for that. There are different ways to do it, and all mentioned in the answers here are valid. Historically the way to do that is by either decreasing your `padding` or your `margin`.

All answers, including the transparent border, are valid and good. Again, it all depends on how everything is used. If there's a SASS variable for `margin` size, for example, you could use that with `-2` or `-[border width variable]`, or include it in the `padding` calculation. I would lean towards this, rather than transparent borders.

```css
.border-blue {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  &:hover {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    margin: 6px;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's likely just a competing answerer; this is a valid solution and the best explanation of the current answer set. By the way, double spaces are ignored in markup, and that convention is only appropriate on typewriters anyway.

Comment: the accepted answer does have a downvote. At any rate, votes (up or down) are the prerogative of the user. While frowned upon, downvoting competing answers is technically a valid technique in the gamification of the site. It is deterred by the fact that downvoting an answer costs you -1 reputation each time.

Comment: @TylerH, another downvote, haha!  For the double spacing thing, I have been doing that for many years.  I learned how to type on a typewriter, so I have been doing it for more than 30 years, haha.  It's nearly impossible for me to not do it.  I missed your comment on that.

Comment: And I often have to go back and remove the second space when I have a comment that is too large.